# how to align a button on the center of the video window using CSS

Tags: css, html

We are writing a video player on the browser where we need to display a play button on the video window. The video window size can be changed by the user. The play button should be displayed on the center of the video window.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Web Player</title>
        <style>
            #app {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                outline: none;
            }
        </style>
     </head>
     <body style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px;">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
         <div id="app"></div>
         <video src="" id="videoID" width="100%"></video>
         <button type="button" id="playVideo">+</button>
     </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#playVideo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    display: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I just gave left and top for playVideo as 200px as I am unable to center the button. I tried with text-align, position and it is not working. We can do this in javascript by using getBoundingClientRect() of video Element and calculating coordinates of button manually. Can any one please let me know if we can center the button on video window without using Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this **(#playVideo)**:

```
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[This](https://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/xwrXwR) page might help you.

Edit: 
Consider creating a div that contains both elements:

```
<div id="container">
     <video src="" id="videoID" width="100%"></video>
     <button type="button" id="playVideo">+</button>
</div>


#container {
  position:relative;
}

#playVideo {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: It is working fine when video occupies whole page. But if I open Javascript console on web browser, the button is not getting displayed on the center of the video window. It is getting displayed on center of the page.

Comment: What about creating a div that include both? Take a look at my edited answer